# DisplayMemberPath reverts back to Name after setting to something else

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, telerik-radlistbox

So I am working on an application that uses the MVVM structure to display data to a user and for them to modify it. The issue I am currently having is this:

Upon selecting an entity from a RadGridView, I then add that member the user looked at to an ObservableCollection. I then see that the RadListBox get's populated(meaning I can hover over the item) but nothing is displayed. The Object is a DataContract I am referencing from the services. I've tried a multitude of fixes but to no avail.

At one point I started using Snoop and noticed that no matter what I set the DisplayMemberPath to the value is DisplayMemberPath would always be "Name". And when I was in Snoop if I changed the value DisplayMemberPath to FirstName the name would pop up in my WPF application.

I've been staring at this for awhile and may just need a new set of eyes. Here is the relevant code:

XAML Code:

```
<Grid MinHeight="70">
  <TextBlock Text="No Members viewed"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible, Mode=OneWay}">
  </TextBlock>
  <telerik:RadListBox Name="uRecenetlyViewMembersListBox"
          DataContext="{Binding MemberInfo}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FirstName}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RecentlyViewedMembers}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecentlyViewedMember,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Visibility="{Binding WorkingListNoRecordsVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      MouseDoubleClick="uRecenetlyViewMembersListBox_MouseDoubleClick"> 
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RecentlyViewedSelectionChanged}">
         </i:InvokeCommandAction>
       </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </telerik:RadListBox>
</Grid>
```

**2/11 EDIT: So I removed the DataContext as it was unclear if it even worked as the context is pointing to correct ViewModel. And changed the DisplayMemberPath and removed binding.**

```xml
<Grid MinHeight="70">
  <TextBlock Text="No Members viewed"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible, Mode=OneWay}">
  </TextBlock>
  <telerik:RadListBox Name="uRecenetlyViewMembersListBox"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RecentlyViewedMembers}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecentlyViewedMember,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Visibility="{Binding WorkingListNoRecordsVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      MouseDoubleClick="uRecenetlyViewMembersListBox_MouseDoubleClick"> 
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RecentlyViewedSelectionChanged}">
         </i:InvokeCommandAction>
       </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </telerik:RadListBox>
</Grid>
```

And c# code:

```cs
private const UInt16 recentlyViewedMemberCapacity = 10;
private ObservableCollection<Member> recentlyViewedMembers;
public ObservableCollection<Member> RecentlyViewedMembers
{
    get { return this.recentlyViewedMembers; }
    set
    {
        if (value != recentlyViewedMembers)
        {
            this.recentlyViewedMembers = value;
            //ugly & inefficient: needs refactoring
            //recentlyViewedMembers = (ObservableCollection<RecentlyViewedMember>)recentlyViewedMembers.OrderByDescending(item => item.DateAdded);
            while (recentlyViewedMembers.Count > recentlyViewedMemberCapacity)
                recentlyViewedMembers.RemoveAt(recentlyViewedMemberCapacity);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.RecentlyViewedMembers);
            ValidateWorkingListVisibility();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DataContract returned from the Service, with only necessary pieces:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Member")]
public class Member : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Member();

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `DisplayMemberPath` to hardcoded property name instead of binding :

```
DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
```

In standard WPF's ListBox, `DisplayMemberPath` should be set to a path (means property name) to be displayed, not the value. So in my understanding, even if the binding works, it will set `DisplayMemberPath` to value of `FirstName` property instead of the property name.

Hope this works for telerik's RadListBox too.

Comment: Yeah I had that on one of my numerous tests. This was the build I had that finally broke the camels back. I'll change it tomorrow and let you know, but if I recall correctly I didn't have DataContext set and the DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName". Could it be that the DataContract doesn't have a RaisePropertyChange?

Comment: Still no change and the DisplayMemberPath still shows as "Name" in snoop